# Android - Video ads in app

Tags: android, video, ads

I was wondering how I could integrate some video ads in my android app. Is there a good tutorial? Can someone explain me step by step shortly?

Comment: https://developer.yahoo.com/flurry/docs/howtos/videoadspace/ there you go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is list of some good video ads website.

[Vungle](http://vungle.com)

[AdColony](http://adcolony.com)

and also unity ads